# how to stop cell editing in JTextPane ,cell editor of JTable

Tags: swing, jtable

I created JTable with JTextPane as cell editor.I want to stop cell editing and want to do some processing if I pressed enter key in JTextPane .And I also want to use single line in JTextPane. So, I add keylistener in JTextPane and call stopCellediting method. But it does not work, focus is in JTextPane and if I click other cell, the selected row and the selected column is not changed.So,please help me to use single line in JTextPane and to stop cell editing if I pressed enter like the default cell editor.Thanks a lot!!

Comment: It would help us to see your code, so we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: Why do you need to use a JTextPane for single line entry? Why not use a JTextField?

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have just come across the same issue, i have solved this by having a custom editor and overriding the default fireEditingCancled

```
private CelEditor extend AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor
{
   /* Other Code here for editor **/

   protected void fireEditingCanceled() 
   { 
          this.stopCellEditing();  
    }
}
```

Took me awhile to figure this out, Also if this does not work you can try using model.setObject(Object, row,col) inside the cancel function.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want a custom cell editor that has a keylistener on it that listens for the "enter" key and then does the processing you want.